# Node.js cookie-parser returns encoded characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, ascii, url-encoding

I'm using cookie-parser for giving user a signed cookie, but I have problems with decoding them manually. Server returns cookies with hidden hex codes (I guess?). Example:

```
app.use(cookieParser('bar'));
...
res.cookie('nickname', 'foo', { signed: true });
```

Then I have a cookie with weird `%3A` characters `nickname=s%3Afoo.FHkzIYqqvAuLEKKzpcNGhMjZQ0G88QpHNtxycPd0GFE` and I can't decode it

```
cookieParser.signedCookie('s%3Afoo.FHkzIYqqvAuLEKKzpcNGhMjZQ0G88QpHNtxycPd0GFE', 'bar')
```

returns the same string. When I change `%3A` to `:` (hex encode?) like

```
cookieParser.signedCookie('s:foo.FHkzIYqqvAuLEKKzpcNGhMjZQ0G88QpHNtxycPd0GFE', 'bar')
```

I got `foo` - the correct value. Does anyone know how to handle it automatically? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: try `cookieParser.signedCookie(unescape('.....'), 'bar')`

Comment: It helped, thank you very much. As I though the problem was in encoding, not in the cookie-parser. Please post your answer below so I can upvote :)

Comment: When posting my solution, I noticed I was a bit sleepy and gave you the *old* way to decode a urlencoded string.  You will want to use `decodeURI` instead as `unescape` is deprecated as of Javascript 1.5 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string you are getting back is [urlencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) ( [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) ) which means that you need to decode it before you can work with it normally. ( *Note: Wikipedia has this listed as 'Percent Encoding'* )

The decode command in JavaScript is [unescape](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/u/unescape.htm) however as of JavaScript 1.5, this command is deprecated and you should use [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI) or [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) instead.

The syntax to use these commands are as follows :

### unescape

```js
   var foo = "Hello%20World"; // encoded string
   var bar = unescape("Hello%20World");
   console.log(bar);
```

### decodeURI

```js
   var foo = "Hello%20World"; // encoded string
   var bar = decodeURI("Hello%20World");
   console.log(bar);
```

### decodeURIComponent

```js
   var foo = "Hello%20World"; // encoded string
   var bar = decodeURIComponent("Hello%20World");
   console.log(bar);
```

*The following charts are from w3schools.com*

### Windows-1252 and UTF-8 Encoding Reference

[image: encoded]

### ASCII Control Characters Encoding Reference

[image]